# Is Kefir an effective treatment for bowel disorders?

Tags: medical-science

[Kefir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kefir) is a fermented milk drink from Russia.

There are some claims that Kefir is effective at treating gastroenteritis and inflammatory or irritable bowel syndrome. A web search for Kefir results in massive amounts of information and even sites dedicated to it.

- [Kefir.net](http://www.kefir.net/kefir-benefits/)

> The regular use of kefir can help relieve all intestinal disorders,
>   promote bowel movement, reduce flatulence and create a healthier
>   digestive system. In addition, its cleansing effect on the whole body
>   helps to establish a balanced inner ecosystem for optimum health and
>   longevity.

One pilot study looked at a restrictive diet, which included several "probiotic" foods Kefir, but did not test it exclusively:

- [Pilot Testing a Novel Treatment for Inflammatory Bowel Disease](http://www.umassmed.edu/uploadedFiles/MBD_Poster59_EDITED_5-15-2011.pdf)
  Barbara Olendzki; Gioia Persuitte; Taryn Silverstein; 
  Katherine Baldwin, David Cave; John Zawacki; Kanishka Bhattacharya, Yunsheng Ma,

> Notably, 9 out of 11 patients were able to be managed without anti-TNF
>   therapy, and 100% of the patients had their symptoms reduced. To make
>   clear recommendations for its use in clinical practice, randomized
>   trials are neededalongside strategies to improve acceptability and
>   compliance with the IBD-AID.

This is a strong result for IBD treatment. Most treatments do not even come close to this result. I also understand that with dietary changes it is more or less impossible to do proper blinding.

I am always wary of digestive system treatments as this has been a very difficult part for medical science to get a grasp on because of the sheer complexity of how everything in the gut interacts.

I am interested in whether Kefir can be successfully used to treat such illnesses.

Comment: Based on a quick review of the literature, it seems [scientists are getting excited by the idea](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2653298/?tool=pmcentrez), but it is still a long way off from being isolated, clinically tested and recommended. Unfortunately, this question looks like it might fall into the "research-level science" basket. Looking forward to being proved wrong (either now, or in ten years' time.)

Comment: I'd be surprised if it would have significantly different effect, than yogurt or buttermilk (quoted  study also includes yogurt alongside with kefir).

Comment: The big question is which probiotic(s) in the Kefir has this effect? The right combination of strains could be the answer.